# Hashing technique for strings with edit distance 2

Tags: string, hash, matching

Is there any hashing techniques which will hash same value for two strings with very few mismatches ? For example, I have two strings `abcdabcdabcd` and `aacdabcdabcd`. I would like to use a hash function which can give same value for the above two strings. I was trying to use `metroHash` and `murmerHash`, but I could not find the way to resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

I challenge your question like this:

Imagine that I have double values like 7.3 and 8.5 and I want them to have the same hash. You would immedietly ask if 9.1 and then 10.0 and then 10.4 and then 10.8 and so forth should get the same hash too, wouldn't you? Because 9.1 is as near to 8.5 as 8.5 is to 7.3.

So for numbers you would partition into [0 ; 1[ , [1 ; 2[ and so forth and assign the same hash to each partition. What would be the analog way to partition strings?

So you have to find distinct areas maybe defined by representants and then generate the hash based on the nearest representant. You could chose the representants "", "a", "aa", "aaa" and so forth and return some hash of the representant that is NEXT to the given value where NEXT may be defined by the Levenshtein distance or by the mere string length.

All in all I guess you are on the wrong track and should explain your original problem in the first place. A hash is not meant to compute any meaningful cluster adress or partition number of a value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I have a set of strings of equal length and I am dealing with Levenshtein distance 1 or 2. I believe the locality sensitive hashing might help.

Comment: Then you may just use the mere string length as hash.

Comment: just wondering how could the hashing of lengths solve the issue.